# Having trouble storing array values in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to explode a string into an array. A fullname to be exploded in firstname, middlename, and lastname.

```
  <?php

    include('conn.php');

    $un=$_POST['uname'];
    $pw=$_POST['pw'];
    $fulnem=$_POST['fullnem'];
    $temp=explode('/',$fulnem);

    $email=$_POST['email'];

    $method="creates";





    $sql="call compactproc('$un', '$pw', '$temp[0]', '$temp[1]', '$temp[2]', '$email', '$method')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result){
    echo "error!";

    }



    ?>
```

Here's the procedure body:

```
BEGIN

IF actions="creates" THEN
INSERT INTO admin_table(Uneym, Pwerd, Firstname, Middlename, Lastname, Email) VALUES(usrname, psword, frstname, midname, lstname, imail);
END IF;
END
```

Only the firstname is stored in the database. Why is it? The midname and lastname doesnt get stored and I get the undefined offset error on the line of the sql query.
can you tell me what's the problem here.

Comment: i don't know why the values that are supposed to be in fname, mname, and lname, are in the field for username: call compactproc('a+b+c', 'a', 'a', '', '', 'a', 'creates')

Comment: Try `var_dump($fulnem, $temp);` right after `$temp=explode('/',$fulnem);`. what does it output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you should not use single quote(') in parameters of call compactproc.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explode with a space    instead of a `/` :

```
 $temp=explode(' ',$fulnem);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try a little error check

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Hope it helps, I had same problem and adding this little snippet solved my problem. Taken straight from W3school.